# Filter multiple models by attribute in ember.js Route

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following RSVP hash in my IndexRoute which finds all slider records ( I need to use a hash because I need to load 2 models on this page). I can call sliders or this.sliders in the index template to successfully pass all the slider objects to a view component.

However, I need to filter these records by the page attribute "index". When I add filterBy to the IndexRoute, no records are returned.

How can I filter these records and use the resulting array in the template?

IndexRoute

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({ 
            sliders: this.store.findAll("slider"), # Adding .filterBy("page", "index") fails to load anything
            products: this.store.findAll("products")
        });
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   {{mainpage-slider sliders=sliders}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the filter to the controller

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({ 
      sliders: this.store.find("slider"), # Adding .filterBy("page", "index") fails to load anything
      products: this.store.find("products")
   });
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  filteredSlider: function(){
    return this.get('sliders').filterBy('page', 'index');
  }.property('sliders.@each.page')
});
```

Comment: Hi KingPin2k just got this working thanks! I just had to change this.get("slider") to this.get("sliders") to reflect the property in the Route hash. Many thanks.